# Tesla to Newtons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, si-units

Is it possible to convert Tesla to Newtons of force?
Or magnetization force H:(A/m) to newtons?

Answer (score 2):

Tesla is a unit of magnetic field, and Newtons are a unit of force. They can't be "converted" to each other as they measure different things. There are various formulas that can determine the force on a magnetic (or electrically charged) object that depend on the magnetic field, but you'll need to be more specific about your situation if you want a way of calculating a force from a magnetic field.

Comment: 1Tesla = 1(Newtons/Ampere)/Meter what does this mean? I want to compare the magnitude of vectors the magnetization force(H in A/m) and Newtons.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=1tesla+%3D+newtons%2Famp%2Fmeter&safe=off

Comment: @XCIX Apples and oranges!

Comment: @XCIX: You can't compare the magnitudes of vectors with incompatible units. It's like asking if 3 hours is more or less than 5 kilograms. That you're trying to do this probably means you're fundamentally misunderstanding the problem you're trying to solve. Try editing your question to add more context.

Comment: @Dan "tesla can also be expressed as:" Please look at this link @ the definitions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_(unit), the reason I asked this question is because of those expressions. I know they are not related, but that is why I asked and I need clarification.

Comment: @Dan It has to do with Lorentz Force I guess, since F = IL x B , Newton = Ampere*Meter x Tesla. Something like that... 1Tesla = 1Newton/Ampere/Meter. Is that not something familiar? Or used in conversions? What is the use of this?

Comment: @XCIX: It's a formula, not a "conversion". If you have some current travelling along some length, then you can calculate the force on that wire from a magnetic field.

Comment: @XCIX: "1 Tesla = 1Newton/Ampere/Meter" This is true. If you want to convert Teslas to Newton/Ampere/Meters, this works just fine, because those units are compatible. You can't just convert Newtons to Tesla, though, you need a formula.

Comment: @Dan Ah here was my mistake. I thought I could convert Tesla in Newton from the follow concept:A/m can be convert to Oe(If it's the measure of field intensity H), Then N = T/Oe, and assume we could get the magnitude of force in newtons by this. My mistake. Although, what do you think about this?

Comment: @XCIX: It doesn't work.

Comment: @Dan Why? And what does Newton/A/m mean, or what can it be useful for?

Comment: @XCIX: Try asking that as another question.

Comment: @Dan done, please check it out: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86976/what-is-the-use-of-this-formula-1-tesla-1-newton-ampere-meter