# What is the use of this formula 1 Tesla = 1 Newton/Ampere/Meter?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, si-units

What does Newtons/Ampere/Meter stand for?
From this formula: 1 Tesla = 1 Newtons/Ampere/meter
what can it be used for? To do what?
Ampere/meter Is the same unit as a field's intensity H? Or what is it?

Edit by public: How can this equation be used with regards to finding the dimensions of different variables?

Comment: $f = B I L$ eqn for the force on a straight wire of length $L$ carrying current $I$ placed in a uniform magnetic field $B$

Answer (score 7):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_%28unit%29):

> A particle carrying a charge of 1 coulomb and passing through a magnetic field of 1 tesla at a speed of 1 meter per second perpendicular to said field experiences a force with magnitude 1 newton, according to the Lorentz force law.

So 1 Tesla = 1N / (1C . 1m/s), and one Coulomb per second is one Ampere giving us 1 Tesla = 1N / (1A . 1m).

Comment: Makes sense. However, why is it stated to be A*m? Instead of A/m? I'm confused mostly about this part. The Ampere-meter being A*m or A/m. Maybe one is S.I the other CGS?

Comment: I assume *Newton/Ampere/Meter* means *(Newton/Ampere)/Meter*, which is the same as *Newton/(Ampere $\times$ Meter)*.

Comment: A/m is unit of the field strength/intensity H. So if the values of H = x, then, A/m = x? H = Coercivity force/field = in A/m.

Comment: @JohnRennine Can it be true?

Comment: @XCIX: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @JohnRennine  
H S.I Unit = A/m? ,A/m is the unit for field strength H correct?

Comment: @JohnRennine I assume it is, the unit for H(The strength/intensity of the field).

Comment: @XCIX: yes, the SI units of H and A/m. If you're asking what the connection between **B** and **H** is then maybe that is a new question.

Comment: @JohnRennine the magnetization force is sometimes denoted as "H", however, the unit of that force is in A/m. If I had a field that H = 100,000 A/m and B = 0.5 Tesla the force would be 50,000 Newtons of force? I'm trying to compare the intensity(i.e magnetization force) to a normal mechanical force, if that makes sense?

Comment: @JohnRennine Some sources state the formula being 1T = 1N * A^-1 * m^-1 Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_(unit)

Comment: @XCIX: $1N * A^{-1} * m^{-1} $ is exactly the same as $1N / (A * m) $

Comment: so that's 50,000N of force? Based on the example above? What experiences such a force? The moments or dipoles? Maybe it's F required to figure out the torque?

Answer (score 1):

Newton / ampere metre - that works out at 742-321-11 = 410 = tesla.

Ampere-metre is used of magnetic pole strentths, eg I.a/l  (current.vector area/length),  this is a kind of 'charge', against which one might measure force/charge=field (here B).

Comment: What does "742-321-11" mean? Where did you get those numbers?

Comment: The numbers are a dimensioal calclation  742=N, 321=A, 11=m, 410=T.  It's home grown.  Also, s=1.

Comment: Why are those numbers chosen? How does the system work?

Comment: The idea was to avoid negative exponents, so i used time, velocity, density, and the magnetic constant µ as base dimensions.  Nearly everything comes out as small powers.  You set time=1, velocity=10, magnetic constant = 100, and charge/area = 300.  length=11, mass=733.  The system was set up like this, because most of these are constant from atom to stars.  Mostly the codata values are 1e-9 raised to the last digit: eg e = 322 gives 1e-18, etc,

Answer (score 0):

It is $\mathrm{N}\mathrm{A}^{-1}\mathrm{m}^{-1}$(Newtons per ampere per meter). Some people write this as if you were using a calculator to work it out (Newtons/Ampere)/Meter and they leave out the brackets.