# What is the pull force of Earth's magnetic field per square metre on one of the magnetic poles?

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields, earth, geomagnetism

I was wondering if anyone knows what is the strength of pull of Earth's magnetic field near magnetic poles. I found that the field strength is approximately 0.65 gauss, but was unable to convert this into an approximate value per square metre in kgf or Newtons on the surface... Could someone please help? I know that the answer would only be a rough approximation at best, but this would still be helpfull.

Comment: This is not Santa related, is it? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86976/ converts Tesla to Newton's.   One gauss equals$ 1×10^{−4}$ tesla (100 μT), so 1 tesla = 10,000 gauss.

Comment: No Rudolf levitation included :D ... I went through the question you quoted and can't work out how to get value of force per area. So 1Tesla=1Newton per 1A per 1 metre? Per metre of what and how do I get the pull strength of the field? Should I square it?

Comment: It's not constant - it varies in direction and magnitude depending upon where you are on the Earth. In fact the North Pole is currently in motion moving from Canada to Siberia. As a general rule, the magnetic north is unreliable near the pole since it's diving toward the surface - small changes result in large variance. But I don't know strength per unit area. Also, it's more likely the magnetic field is result of the rotation of electric currents since the center of the Earth is to hot to create a magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit like asking how much force the Earth's gravitational force exerts. The gravitational force on an object is its weight, and (all other things being equal) more massive objects weigh more.

The main effect of the Earth's field on a magnet such as a compass needle is a torque, which gives it an angular acceleration if it is free to rotate. And the amount of this torque depends on the magnetic moment **μ** of the magnet. In SI units, that moment is measured in ampere-metres squared (A‧$\mathrm{m}^2$). Also, it depends on the relative directions of the Earth's magnetic field (**B**) and the magnetic moment through the vector equation **τ** = **μ** x **B**. At the North or South magnetic poles, this field is vertical, so if a magnet is horizontal, the torque will also be horizontal at right angles to the magnet. This will make the magnet rotate upwards (at the S magnetic pole) or downwards (at the N magnetic pole).

Now, in SI units, the Earth's magnetic field at the North or South Pole is 65 μT, and a magnetic compass needle has a moment of "not less than" 90 mA‧$\mathrm{m}^2$ (according to one guide I found). So the torque on a horizontal needle is about 6×$10^{-6}$ newton-metres (N‧m). As the magnet rotates until it is vertical, the torque decreases until it is zero.

Maybe, after all that, what you really want is a linear force (your "pull force"). That's actually related to a gradient: **F** = ∇(**m**‧**B**), where the delta symbol indicates a gradient. For the Earth's field, that would be really small!